# iOS TabbarViewController hide the tab bar when application become active issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, hide

I am able hide tabBar when ViewController pushed(load) by using following code:

`- (BOOL)hidesBottomBarWhenPushed
{
    return YES;
}`

But when the application goes in background and applicationDidBecomeActive, the tabBar appears back. I have tried

self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;

but it didn't work. 
I can hide it with by updating the frame of tabBar

```
if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
{
   [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.size.height, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
}
```

Is it the best way to do this task and acceptable by Apple App Store?

Comment: Interesting that it re-appears when the app becomes active again.

Comment: Yes, it's acceptable to the App Store. Also, I prefer creating my own tabbar controller alike controller to have same functionality like tabbarcontroller plus customizations like you are doing, because of the feeling like I'm breaking something (which of course doesn't let me sleep tight).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using methods to fuzz around with the tab bar (There ain't any good and useful methods available and setting its hiden attribut does not have any affect for some reason.) you can simply move it off the screen. Get old of a reference to the tab bar and set its frame in a way, that its `origin.x` is larger than the screen's (or `self.view`'s) `size.width` and/or do the same with `origin.y` and `size.height`.